# Home and End keys not working in vi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vi

In Insert mode, when I press End I get an F where the cursor is and Insert mode is canceled.  This works on one system and not another.  I have checked what is installed (vim, vim-common, vim-runtime,vim-tiny) and the version (both are 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.3) as well as what vi and vim point to (both point to /usr/bin/vim.basic). /etc/vim/vimrc* are identical as is .vimrc (set no compatible and colorscheme torte).  What else do I check?

Comment: Is there a difference in what `$TERM` is set to in the shell? How about `:set term?` inside Vim? How about `:set t_@7? t_kh?` (these are the terminfo/termcap codes for the "End" and "Home" keys...)

Comment: Thank you so much - this is the answer to my question (post it as an answer, I'll accept it).  $TERM was set to linux, changing it to xterm-256color solved my problem (didn't try any other settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with how `$TERM` is set in your system.

On the problem system, you had it as `TERM=linux`, which is applicable to the Linux console and uses different escape sequences for the special keys than the xterm settings.

Setting it to `TERM=xterm` or `TERM=xterm-256color` or similar should fix it.